# More Efficient Way to Add Markers to Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am building this JS programmatically. Each marker is being represented by separate variables like marker_0,marker_1, etc... This works but is there a way to generate the markers & info windows in a more efficient/elegant way?

```
            <script  type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.056466,-85.3312009),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

        //**************************************************************
        //Add 1st marker
        //**************************************************************
        var contentString_0 ='<strong>Club name: Fort Wayne Time Corners</strong>';
        var infowindow_0 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString_0
        });


        var image_0 = '/js/markers/marker1.png';
        var Latlng_0 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.057814980291,-85.329851919709);
        var marker_0 = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: Latlng_0,
              title:"0",
              icon: image_0});

        marker_0.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker_0, 'click', function() {
            infowindow_0.open(map,marker_0);
        });

    //**************************************************************
        //Add 2nd marker
        //**************************************************************
        var contentString_1='<strong>Club name: Roanoke</strong>';

        var infowindow_1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString_1
        });


        var image_1 = '/js/markers/marker2.png';
        var Latlng_1 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.17805990,-85.4436640);
        var marker_1 = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: Latlng_1,
        title:"1",
        icon: image_1});

        marker_1.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker_1, 'click', function() {
            infowindow_1.open(map,marker_1);
        });


}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;            
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this easily:

1. Create an array of data that describes each marker.
2. Write a function that adds a single marker based on the description in one entry of that array.
3. Call that function for each entry in that array.

So the only part you have to generate dynamically is that array of data; all of the actual marker code is shared for all markers.

Like this:

```
var map;

var places = [
    {
        lat: 41.057814980291,
        lng: -85.329851919709,
        image: 'marker1',
        title: '0',
        club: 'Fort Wayne Time Corners'
    },
    {
        lat: 41.17805990,
        lng: -85.4436640,
        image: 'marker2',
        title: '1',
        club: 'Roanoke'
    }
];

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.056466,-85.3312009),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map-canvas"), 
        mapOptions
    );

    for( var i = 0;  i < places.length;  i++ ) {
        addPlace( places[i] );
    }

    function addPlace( place ) {
        var content = '<strong>Club name: ' + place.club + '</strong>';
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: content
        });

        var image = '/js/markers/' + place.image + '.png';
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( place.lat, place.lng );
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            title: place.title,
            icon: image
        });

        marker.setMap( map );

        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open( map, marker );
        });
    }
}

function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```